# Getting duplicate columns in query

Tags: php, mysql

```
$sql = "select * from import1";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

$stmt->execute(array())
    or die("Error in Selecting: " . $sql);

$data = $stmt->fetchAll();

print_r($data);
```

The result has the columns twice.  Why?  How do I stop this?  I only want the named columns.  The next step is to dump the array to JSON, and then import on the other side is getting screwed up by having extra unexpected columns.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [DATE] => 2018-02-28
        [0] => 2018-02-28
        [GRADE] => 6
        [1] => 6
        [FIRST] => Kyle
        [2] => Kyle
```

Comment: why are you fetching all *and* doing a `print_r()`? If that isn't the issue, then try DISTINCT and/or GROUP BY.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner That will fix duplicate rows, not duplicate columns.

Comment: Oh, OK @Barmar I misunderstood; I stand corrected.

Comment: Side note: There is no need to `prepare/execute` here, since you're not really using a prepared statement, per se. This can be cut down to simply using `query()`.

Comment: True until the next bit of code gets added.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Specify the format of the response using the argument to `fetchAll`.

```
$data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

You can also specify the default format when creating the PDO object.

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_database", $db_username, $db_password, 
    array(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```